# git remote add clarification

Tags: git, gitlab

I just set up a local git repo -> github. Everything is working fine but would like some clarifications on the github walkthrough so I have a better understanding of what's going on.

1. `git branch -M main` - is this simply designating what branch to put my files into on github? If I had changed my github repo branch to "thunder" would the code then be `git branch -M thunder`?
2. `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project.git` - What exactly does 'origin' mean?
3. `git push -u origin main` - Again, why 'origin' and what does the 'main' do?

This all does work. I'm able to simply `git push` to push my files. I just don't fully understand what some of the code means. Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

-`git branch -M main` creates a new branch on in your local repo named 'main'

-`git remote add origin` - `origin` is the name given to the remote repo

-`git push -u origin main` - pushes your files to the remote repo (name origin) to the branch named 'main'

Comment: Yes, you are correct in all these. 

You can also use `git checkout -b <new_branch_name>` to create a new branch and checkout (move) to it at the same time

Comment: Interesting. Let's say I do `git branch -M main` then `git push -u origin main`. Anything pushed would be pushed to the main branch on the local repo. Afterwards say I create a second branch `git branch -M sub`. Then I go to `git push` I'll have an issue yes? It's assuming I'm still in the `main` branch because I never `git checkout sub` . Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Not exactly. 
When you do `git branch -M sub` you are creating a new branch called `sub` and also moving to that branch.The `-M` argument does this. If you would have done just `git branch sub` then it would have created the branch `sub` but wouldnt have moved you to it, so you would face an issue.

Comment: So essentially `git branch -M sub` is the same as `get checkout -b sub` ?

Would I then have to change the upstream in order to simply use `git push`? So `git branch -M sub` then `git push -u origin sub` BEFORE doing `git push`?

Comment: Yes they are kinda the same. When you do -u, you basically tell git that next time I do just `git pull` or `git push` you know which branch to look at. 
So, yes, you can do it for the first time using `git push -u origin sub`. After that git always keeps it in mind.

Comment: Awesome - thank you very much for the clarifications. Much appreciated!